# JMeter - regular expression extractor - multiple lines of html

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jmeter

Using JMeter, I am trying to get a specific value from an entire HTML response page and store it as a variable. The problem is that the value I need extracted is on the 3rd line of HTML code with the identifier on the 1st line.

`<td><span class="outputLabel1">Total</span></td>
<td><span class="outputText"></span></td>
<td width="15%" style="text-align: right;"><span class="outputText">1,068.00</span></td>`

I am needing to extract the "1,068.00" out of the last line, but still need to match "Total" from the first line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `(?s)` to match the line.

Below regular expression would give you the 'Total'.

```
Total(?s).*class="outputText">(.+?)</span>
```

Comment: That gets me what I need. I can parse the rest out via a string in BeanShell. Thx